# Why do my objects disappear when I add a Subdivision Surface modifier?

Tags: modifiers, subdivision-surface, visibility

Whenever I add a Subdivision Surface modifier to any object, it immediately disappears from the screen. It does not matter what kind of object I apply the modifier to. When I switch to editing mode, I can see the wire frame with the nodes of the object, but not its actual surface. In object mode it is just completely invisible. Do I need to change a setting?

Before adding modifier
[image]

With modifier
[image]

Comment: could you please show some screenshots? It may help to understand what's happening, or even share one of your objects

Comment: Does this happen in all your blender projects or just with a specific file? If it's the later one can you please share the file?

Comment: It happens in all of my projects. And I added some screenshots.

Comment: it looks like a bug, is it the same with the previous versions of Blender?

Comment: Yup, it works fine in 3.0.1. Thanks! Should I report the bug somewhere?

Comment: maybe here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JTD0OJq_rF4 ... but I guess it has been fixed if 3.01 works

Answer (score 15):

The same problem occurred to me and I have fixed it.

Click "Edit > Preferences..." on the menu bar to open the Preferences Window. Then Switch to the "Viewport" Tab, click "Subdivision" and uncheck "GPU subdivision" below. Now the object should be visible.

[image: Preferences Window]

I don't know if it is caused by my old GPU or a software bug. My GPU is AMD Radeon R9 370. My Blender version is 3.1.0.

Hopefully helpful.

Comment: i was about to create the same question but this post pop up and thanks for your answer.