# Subdivision Surface Modifier completely broken for me since 3.2 update

Tags: subdivision-surface

To keep it short. Since the new update, the subdivision modifier makes my mesh disappear completely, I fiddled around with the *advanced* options, checked if it may be a rendering issue, reverted to factory default and nothing worked. I have no clue at this point. It still shows the vertices and stuff in editor mode, but it doesn't render the subdivided mesh in viewport. In object mode, it draws a weird diagonal line. Applying the modifier still works, but unapplied it makes the mesh disappear completely, rendering it useless. Please help :(

[image: before adding modifier]

[image: after adding modifier]

[image: in edit mode]

[image]

Comment: Try updating your graphics drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a fix here.
[Why do my objects disappear when I add a Subdivision Surface modifier?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/255981/why-do-my-objects-disappear-when-i-add-a-subdivision-surface-modifier)
Apparently, some Graphics Cards don't support the subdivision thingy.
Just turn off "GPU Subdivision" in the Viewport section in the Preferences.
[image]